# Get same values in DropDownList yii2

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, yii2

I have a DropDownList duplicate three times, but I used 3 models and 3 select ID to make a difference, but I got the same values of the last one duplicated on others.
the model `$modelDevisReduction1` is a model of table `Reduction(type,taux)`, so for each select I have a 'taux'.
this is my code:

```
 /* Reduction 1 */
<?= $form->field($modelDevisReduction1, 'idReduction')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Reduction::find()->all(),'idReduction','libelle'), ['prompt'=>'Sélectionner la Reduction','id'=>'DevisReductionType-1'] )->label(false); ?>

<?=  $form->field($modelDevisReduction1,'taux')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'id'=>'DevisReductionTaux-1'])->label(false); ?>

/* Reduction 2 */
<?= $form->field($modelDevisReduction2, 'idReduction')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Reduction::find()->all(),'idReduction','libelle'), ['prompt'=>'Sélectionner la Reduction','id'=>'DevisReductionType-2'] )->label(false); ?>

<?=  $form->field($modelDevisReduction2,'taux')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'id'=>'DevisReductionTaux-2'])->label(false); ?>

/* Reduction 3 */
<?= $form->field($modelDevisReduction3, 'idReduction')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Reduction::find()->all(),'idReduction','libelle'), ['prompt'=>'Sélectionner la Reduction','id'=>'DevisReductionType-3'] )->label(false); ?>

<?=  $form->field($modelDevisReduction3,'taux')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'id'=>'DevisReductionTaux-3'])->label(false); ?>
```

this is the controller actionCreate code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{

    $model = new Devis();
    $modelDevisReduction1 = new DevisReduction();
    $modelDevisReduction2 = new DevisReduction();
    $modelDevisReduction3 = new DevisReduction();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  
    $modelDevisReduction2->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && 
    $modelDevisReduction1->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && 
    $modelDevisReduction3->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        echo "Reference => ".$model->reference;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "dateCreation => ".$model->dateCreation;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "contact => ".$model->contact;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "delaiLivraison => ".$model->delaiLivraison;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "commercial => ".$model->commercial;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "valableJusqua => ".$model->valableJusqua;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "dateRelance => ".$model->dateRelance;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "etat => ".$model->etat;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "modePaiement => ".$model->modePaiement;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "delaiPaiement => ".$model->delaiPaiement;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Reduction 1 : ". $modelDevisReduction1->idReduction;
        echo "Taux de Reduction 1 : ". $modelDevisReduction1->taux;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Reduction 2 : ". $modelDevisReduction2->idReduction;
        echo "Taux de Reduction 2 : ". $modelDevisReduction2->taux;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Reduction 3 : ". $modelDevisReduction3->idReduction;
        echo "Taux de Reduction 3 : ". $modelDevisReduction3->taux;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "Articl ".$modelArticleDevis->idArticle;

        die;
        /* $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['index']); */

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelDevisReduction1' => $modelDevisReduction1,
            'modelDevisReduction2' => $modelDevisReduction2,
            'modelDevisReduction3' => $modelDevisReduction3,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is the form:
[image]

In results i got the values of the therd select duplicated on others (Ristourne ID = 3, Taux = 4)

Comment: update your question and show the related controller/action code

Comment: wath I want here is to insert multiple option in one model

Comment: @MALKIMOHAMED Please show us your post datas. Post datas can be seen from Yii2 debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your code. In your `actionCreate()` you have created three model objects of the same type `DevisReduction`.

```
$modelDevisReduction1 = new DevisReduction();
$modelDevisReduction2 = new DevisReduction();
$modelDevisReduction3 = new DevisReduction();
```

In the view you have written the code as,

```
<?= $form->field($modelDevisReduction1, 'idReduction')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Reduction::find()->all(),'idReduction','libelle'), ['prompt'=>'Sélectionner la Reduction','id'=>'DevisReductionType-1'] )->label(false); ?>

<?= $form->field($modelDevisReduction2, 'idReduction')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Reduction::find()->all(),'idReduction','libelle'), ['prompt'=>'Sélectionner la Reduction','id'=>'DevisReductionType-2'] )->label(false); ?>

<?= $form->field($modelDevisReduction3, 'idReduction')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Reduction::find()->all(),'idReduction','libelle'), ['prompt'=>'Sélectionner la Reduction','id'=>'DevisReductionType-3'] )->label(false); ?>
```

But as **$modelDevisReduction1,$modelDevisReduction2 and $modelDevisReduction** are referencing three objects of the same type **DevisReduction**.The view will be rendered with the name attribute as `DevisReduction[idReduction]` for fields **$modelDevisReduction1, $modelDevisReduction2 and $modelDevisReduction3**.So when you submit the form, the last select box value (field $modelDevisReduction3) will get taken.This is exactly happening in your case.Same with the case of input field `DevisReduction[taux]`.You can further confirm by.

1. Inspecting the rendered view html.
2. Checking the form post datas.

My suggestion for a solution to your above problem is that you create a custom form model as given below.

```
<?php

class DevisReductionForm extends yii\base\Model {

    public $idReduction1;
    public $idReduction2;
    public $idReduction3;
    public $taux1;
    public $taux2;
    public $taux3;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules() {
        $rules = [
                    [['idReduction1', 'idReduction1', 'idReduction1', 'taux1', 'taux2', 'taux3'], 'required'],
        ];

        return array_merge($rules, parent::rules());
    }

}
```

Your controller code should be like

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    //create object of custom form model DevisReductionForm given above
    $modelDeviceReduction = new DevisReductionForm ();

    if ($modelDeviceReduction->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
    {
         $modelDevisReduction1 = new DevisReduction();
         $modelDevisReduction2 = new DevisReduction();
         $modelDevisReduction3 = new DevisReduction();

         $modelDevisReduction1->idReduction =  $modelDeviceReduction->idReduction1
         $modelDevisReduction2->idReduction =  $modelDeviceReduction->idReduction2
         $modelDevisReduction3->idReduction =  $modelDeviceReduction->idReduction3

         $modelDevisReduction1->taux = $modelDeviceReduction->taux1
         $modelDevisReduction2->taux = $modelDeviceReduction->taux2
         $modelDevisReduction3->taux = $modelDeviceReduction->taux3
          //write other codes


    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'modelDeviceReduction ' => $modelDeviceReduction ,

        ]);
    }
}
```

In your view

```
/* Reduction 1 */
<?= $form->field($modelDeviceReduction, 'idReduction1')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Reduction::find()->all(),'idReduction','libelle'), ['prompt'=>'Sélectionner la Reduction','id'=>'DevisReductionType-1'] )->label(false); ?>

<?=  $form->field($modelDeviceReduction,'taux1')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'id'=>'DevisReductionTaux-1'])->label(false); ?>

/* Reduction 2 */
<?= $form->field($modelDeviceReduction, 'idReduction2')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Reduction::find()->all(),'idReduction','libelle'), ['prompt'=>'Sélectionner la Reduction','id'=>'DevisReductionType-2'] )->label(false); ?>

<?=  $form->field($modelDeviceReduction,'taux2')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'id'=>'DevisReductionTaux-2'])->label(false); ?>

/* Reduction 3 */
<?= $form->field($modelDeviceReduction, 'idReduction3')->dropDownList( ArrayHelper::map(Reduction::find()->all(),'idReduction','libelle'), ['prompt'=>'Sélectionner la Reduction','id'=>'DevisReductionType-3'] )->label(false); ?>

<?=  $form->field($modelDeviceReduction,'taux3')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'id'=>'DevisReductionTaux-3'])->label(false); ?>
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: @MALKIMOHAMED My suggestion is that you use a custom form model for your view

Comment: you mean by using the POST in controller to get data ?

Comment: No your form  should be independent of your models (in yii2 there is provision for creating custom form model),so that in controller you can assign values to your models based on that

Comment: I will give the solution code also in the answer,please wait for a while

Comment: Glad to know :)